# How to paint custom controls and then propagate events?

Tags: qt

For example, one widget I am trying to create is a mix of `QToolButton` and `QLineEdit`.

When `leaveEvent()` occurs, it appears like a `QToolButton` with the icon/text on the left & the menu-arrow on the right `(QToolButton.MenuButtonPopup`). When `enterEvent()` occurs, the left half of the button (icon/text) becomes a `QLineEdit`, while the right half is still a drop down menu.

I have been trawling through whatever forums google search brings up, and while I loosely understand how to paint it, how do I connect the events properly? If I paint the `QLineEdit`, how do I get that part of the custom widget to act and respond like a `QLineEdit`? (Python preferred, C++ is ok)

[`QComboBox` will not work, and definitely the other widgets I'd like to create don't have any approximate equivalent. Also, I know I can build a widget with other simpler widgets, and then mess with the style sheets to achieve something similar looking, but I know there is an answer to the above, because Qt does it, and it would have better cross-system styling then writing custom style sheets.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to understanding this issue is the realization that there is no behavior without an actual widget being present. So, merely using the style mechanism to paint a given control is not sufficient. You need an instance of `QWidget` (say, a `QToolButton` or `QLineEdit`). Once you have that, you may as well have it as a child, and let Qt's event propagation handle dispatching the events appropriately. This takes care of a lot of headache.

If you want the behavior of a tool button with an embedded line edit, it'd be simplest to actually have the line edit as a child widget of the tool button. You inherit from `QToolButton`, and show/hide the line edit child as appropriate. This inheritance also lets you leverage the key protected method present in control widgets: `initStyleOption`. Using composition (has-a) instead of inheritance (is-a), you'd need to have an adapter class that merely exposes `QToolButton::initStyleOption` method to a friend class.

Your intended behavior is quite problematic from the focus viewpoint. The button should be editable **and** clickable while using only the keyboard. It is **insufficient** to merely use the mouse enter/leave events to expose the line editor. A reasonable approach may be to enter the editing mode upon pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd> - yes, those are two different keys!

You also need to understand how Qt's accessibility works, and ensure that your widget behaves appropriately - I haven't addressed that at all. All in all, designing controls (as opposed to merely visualization widgets) is not a trivial task, and you always need to think twice if you really need to "tweak" a standard control other than by styling it.

The code below demonstrates a rather minimal implementation that still behaves reasonably with regards to focus. I have not tested it on anything but Qt 4.8.5 and 5.2 on OS X 10.9, so YMMV, but I'd hope it'll work with any reasonable platform style.

Final nitpick: I don't quite understand what you mean by "QComboBox will not work". Your implementation is essentially a bastardized combo box that doesn't play well with typical HIG (human interface guidelines). You're basically making a toolbutton-based combo box bastard child that looks plainly weird. It is not a combo box, the menu is completely separate from the contents of the button. What's the point?

[image: screenshot]

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QToolButton>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QStyle>
#include <QStyleOptionButton>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QDebug>

class EditButton : public QToolButton {
    Q_OBJECT
    QLineEdit * m_edit;
    QRect m_textGeometry;
    Q_PROPERTY(QString text READ text WRITE setText NOTIFY newText USER true)
public:
    EditButton(QWidget * parent = 0) : QToolButton(parent),
        m_edit(new QLineEdit(this))
    {
        m_edit->hide();
        connect(m_edit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), SIGNAL(newText(QString)));
        connect(m_edit, SIGNAL(editingFinished()), SLOT(hideEditor()));
        setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
    }
    QString text() const { return m_edit->text(); }
    void setText(const QString & text) {
        if (text == m_edit->text()) return;
        m_edit->setText(text);
        QToolButton::setText(text);
        emit newText(text);
    }
    Q_SIGNAL void newText(const QString &);
protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * ev) {
        QToolButton::resizeEvent(ev);
        setEditGeometry();
    }
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * ev) {
        if (ev->key() == Qt::Key_Enter || ev->key() == Qt::Key_Return) {
            showEditor();
            return;
        }
        QToolButton::keyPressEvent(ev);
    }
    void enterEvent(QEvent * ev) {
        showEditor();
        QToolButton::enterEvent(ev);
    }
    void leaveEvent(QEvent * ev) {
        hideEditor();
        QToolButton::leaveEvent(ev);
    }
private:
    Q_SLOT void hideEditor() {
        QToolButton::setText(m_edit->text());
        setFocusProxy(0);
        m_edit->hide();
        update();
    }
    void showEditor() {
        setEditGeometry();
        m_edit->show();
        setFocusProxy(m_edit);
        setFocus();
    }
    void setEditGeometry() {
        QStyleOptionToolButton opt;
        initStyleOption(&opt);
        QRect r = style()->subControlRect(QStyle::CC_ToolButton, &opt, QStyle::SC_ToolButton, this);
        m_edit->setGeometry(r);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget window;
    QGridLayout * l = new QGridLayout(&window);
    EditButton * btn = new EditButton;
    btn->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    QMenu * menu = new QMenu(btn);
    menu->addAction("Action!");
    btn->setMenu(menu);
    btn->setPopupMode(QToolButton::MenuButtonPopup);
    btn->setText("Foo Bar Baz");
    l->addWidget(btn);
    l->addWidget(new QPushButton("Focus Test Button"));
    window.show();
    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Thanks! The point is: I want a toolbar widget for presenting and editing a css property, both directly & with an associated menu of tools. A combo box doesn't provide a QMenu, and it doesn't appear like a toolbutton when not in use (flat with the toolbar), which I desire. And I can't figure out how to put a lineedit side by side with a button so that they look fused under one border like in a combobox/toolbutton. Sure, I could ignore all this, but I'm a bit ocd about it looking just right...

Comment: It looks perfect if you subtract 2 from all edges of its rectangle in setEditGeometry() and setFrame(False).

Comment: @Jeff: A combo box could be made to work like you want, but it'd probably be harder, so you're right.